# upArrow symbol is not rendered in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a problem regarding symbol https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+1F861

```
:after{
            content: "\01F861";
}
```

Every browser displays normally this element except IE.

Does anyone know workaround with it?

Comment: What font are you using? For a workaround, try `\2191`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code, it will display a square in IE browser, it means the font used does not have the glyph for that character.

As a workaround, try to use the [CSS Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_entities.asp). Please check the following sample:

```
<style>
    .ribbon {
        background-color: #5BC8F7;
    }
        .ribbon::after {
            content: " \2191";
            background-color: #FFBA10;
        }
</style>
<span class="ribbon">Look at the orange box after this text. </span>
```

The result in IE browser as below:

[image]